# Interpretation of the name of an ITU-T document

Tags: layer3, standardisation, documentation

I'm reading a document that cites a standard called ITU-T SG 13 Q5 WG. I believe that SG 13 stands for Study Group 13 and Q5 refers to Question 5. However, I don't know what WG stands for. And most importantly, I have no clue where to find this document.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: "WG" usually means Working Group, but in this context I have no idea what it means. I assume you found: https://www.itu.int/itu-t/workprog/wp_search.aspx?Q=5/13

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have used this tool, but I was no successful in finding a document that would fit.